# ld: duplicate symbol

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I'm working on a school project and I'm getting some weird errors from Xcode. I'm using TextMate's Command+R function to compile the project. Compilation seems to work okay but linking fails with an error message I don't understand.

ld output:

> ld: duplicate symbol text_field(std::basic_istream >&)in /path/final/build/final.build/Release/final.build/Objects-normal/ppc/generics.o and /path/final/build/final.build/Release/final.build/Objects-normal/ppc/main.o
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Below is my file io_functions.cpp This is the only declaration of text_field in the entire project.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

#ifndef ENDF
#define ENDF '|'
#define ENDR '\n'

/**
reads one field from a given input stream
Usage: var = text_field(in)
*/
string text_field(istream &in){
    string s;
    getline(in, s, ENDF);
    return s; 
}

long long_field(istream &in){
    return atol(text_field(in).c_str()); 
}

int int_field(istream &in){
    return atoi(text_field(in).c_str()); 
}

double double_field(istream &in){
    return atof(text_field(in).c_str()); 
}

#endif
```

What is going wrong? For a number of reasons I don't want to post my project's entire source.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My first thought was that you're including it twice on the linker command but it appears to be complaining about having the same function in `main.o` and `generics.o`.

So it looks like you're including the `io_functions.cpp` file into the `main.cpp` and `generics.cpp` which is a bad idea at the best of times.

You should have a header file (e.g., `io_functions.h`) that specifies everything contained in `io_functions.cpp` and include that *header* file into the other two.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like io_functions.cpp is being included twice (once by generics.cpp, once by main.cpp).

Comment: Doesn't #ifndef prevent that from happening?

Comment: Only within the compilation unit - here you have two separate compilation units.  The ifndef would stop you from including the file twice in main.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

Use "inline" keyword decorate duplicate method

```
inline string text_field(istream &in)
```

Inline functions are actual functions whose copy of the function body are injected directly into each place the function is called.

For details, please see the [article](https://chunminchang.github.io/blog/post/how-to-avoid-duplicate-symbols-when-compiling)